# Best way to pass data needed for a later (not following) fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-architecture

I have an application that needs to collect some data before doing it's main job.
So, the first fragment collects data, the second fragment collects data and then the third fragment uses the data.
The problem is: data in the first fragment is uncorrelated to the data I collect in the second fragment.
How can I pass the data from the first fragment to the third? Should I incrementally pass all the data I collect in the next fragment arguments, or should I store them elsewhere? I'd really like to know what the best practice is.

---

[explicative image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwYij.png)

---

I won't use a database, since I don't need to permanently store the data.
Thank you!

Comment: set the data in the activity or a shared view model

Comment: you can pass through bundle in fragment or you can store in sharedPrefrence and also you can set the data into parent  activity and get this data from any child fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for any best practices, the best answer is "it depends".

If your app is really small and simple then it's okay to pass data from one screen to another in the arguments bundle.

A more complex approach is to store data somewhere outside of these `Fragment` lifecycles.
It's a general rule you can implement as you want. A couple of examples below:

- Data can be stored on `Application` class level. `Application` class runs for all application lifecycle. Every fragment can get `Application` instance from its activity like `activity?.getApplication()`.
- Data can be stored on `Activity` level if all fragments run in a single activity. `Activity` can be obtained from `Fragment` using `activity` or `requireActivity()`.
- Data can be stored on a parent fragment level if all fragments run in this parent fragment. It can be obtained from child fragments using `parentFragment`.

All these approaches suppose you to cast some "parent" thing to specific interface or implementation. For example, if your fragments run in the `MainActivity` which is stores some `val data: Data` as its property, then you should use it something like this: `(requireActivity() as MainActivity).data`

Clarification on a couple of popular answers:

- The `Shared ViewModel` is just a special case of activity-level approach as `ViewModel` instance is stored in `Activity` scope.
- The `SharedPrefrences` like any "database" approach is a special case of application-level approach as SharedPreferences is stored on application-level (in the file storage) no matter where you create its instance. (And SharedPreferences persists data across application starts, so it's not your option)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mentioned "Shared ViewModel" technique, Androidx introduced new "[Fragment result Api](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result)" starting with "[Fragment](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment)" library v1.3.0-alph04 (currently in beta) which could be used for communication between pair of Fragments or Activity-Fragment.

A Fragment/Activity set a listener in `FragmentManager` by specifying a key and other Fragment/Activity send data (in form of a `Bundle`) to the listener with that key. If there's no listener for the key, `FragmentManager` keeps newest data until a listener gets registered.
Pay attention that listener and result must be set on same `FragmentManager` instance.

I my opinion, its good for signals (events), not for sharing data. A situation I found it useful, was sending "onWindowFocusChanged" from Activity to Fragment. In case of sharing data, Shared ViewModel is better.